# Pan and Zoom via mouse not working in New Data Frame?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.5, data-frame, pan, mouse-wheel

Inserted a new data frame for a small overview map in the corner of my display. Left click and selected properties, set the same coordinate system as the larger display, set the Extent Indicators to the Layers data frame, and left the extents as Automatic.

I select a GIS basemap as the background in the new data frame and can see the little red box showing the location of the larger display. My problem is, I cannot use the mouse or mouse wheel to pan or zoom in this New Data Frame box. I can set the scale in the scale bar and also use the magnifying-glass buttons but not my mouse.

Suggestion commonly found on google searches: make sure I have the Tools checked and not just Layout Tools. I do. Left click on the gray space near the toolbars, I have Tools and Layout Tools checked.

A lot of people seem to have their movement buttons grayed out. I do not! None of the zoom/pan buttons are ever grayed out. I can click them and my mouse arrow changes into the little hand, I just cannot pan or zoom using my mouse or mouse wheel if I double click into the New Data Frame, I have to use the magnifying glasses.

I did find a work around but I don't know how it's working: when I save and close out of the MXD and then open it up again, I can double click into the New Data Frame and the pan and zoom respond to my mouse and mouse wheel.

I am using ArcMAP 10.5.1 for desktop. This has been a nuisance but since I know a work around it is not impeding my work....I am just hoping to finally get an answer once and for all.

Edit: Here is a step-by-step of what I am doing and where I think the program is not working as it should.

- Using ArcMap 10.5.1 for desktop
- Open new MXD and save to local location with simple name
- Set coordinate system and add GIS basemap layer
- zoom in to desired location and set scale (panning and zooming with mouse and mouse wheel works fine here)
- check that both tools and layout tools are checked
- insert new data frame and set active
- set to same coordinate system and add GIS basemap
- Open properties and set extent indicators to layers, close properties and little red square is visible in new data frame
- double click inside new data frame. Edge of data frame is striped grey showing that I am inside of it but mouse and mouse wheel still move/zoom the layout view, not the data frame. This is where I think the program is not working correctly and if I want to adjust the scale of my new data frame I have to use the magnifying glass tools + the scale bar.
- However, if I save and exit and immediately open the same MXD, I can double click into the new data frame, select the pan button (arrow changes to the little hand), and use the mouse/mouse wheel to pan and zoom. A good work around but I feel like the program should allow me to do this whenever I first insert a New Data Frame.
- Please not that I have not added any features or shapefiles to this example MXD but I have had this problem with inserting new data frames in MXD's that also have callouts, shapefiles, etc displayed.

Comment: To try and get a reproducible procedure on test data I think you should start a new Blank Map and then, starting with the addition of an Basemap, record in detail every step you perform up until the point where you think the software is not working as expected.  Your description already has good detail but in this instance I think we need to aim for even more because we don't know what's in your map prior to you adding the new data frame.

Comment: Thank you I will update as soon as have a set of steps in detail